# what does this mean " I got 70 + application forms"

Tags: american-english, british-english, symbols

Today I saw, someone has written

> I got 70+ application forms

What is the purpose of the plus sign in that statement?

Answer (score 1):

It means "more than 70", or "70 or more". In informal speech it would be read as "seventy plus".

Comment: do we use in Academic writing as well

Comment: @Yusufahmad I wouldn't. Phrases like "more than 70" or even "in excess of 70" are more formal. "70+" is quite informal.

Comment: so we should avoid using "70+" in academic writing but rather we can write "seventy or more". correct me if I am wrong

Comment: No, you're right. _At least seventy_ is another common way of phrasing it. In academic writing I'm wondering why you would not be precise with the number.

Comment: @ColinFine                                                         I guess we can't be precise always as matter of fact we may not have the exact amount... to write that is why what if we write " 70+"           :)

Comment: @ColinFine - One example: I'm actually in the process of tabulating user statistics of a new facility at work. I wasn't overseeing the facility right when it opened and we didn't begin tracking user traffic until I gained oversight, so I only have approximate data for those first few few weeks the facility was open. And of course, there's always data corruption: contaminated materials, subjects withdrawing from the study, etc.